# What is the difference between point-to-point and end-to-end encryption/security?

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption

Could some one explain me the difference between point-to-point and end-to-end security?

Comment: @PravinPawar Given the question and the answers here are rather generic, I don't think this should be closed as a dupe of a WCF-specific question. This can serve as a good canonical for other questions about end-to-end or point-to-point encryption.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Point to Point - One direct Connection

[image]

End to End - A Connection with something in the middle

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Point to Point is transport layer encryption. Data is encrypted in the transport layer e.g. (Https)

End to End is Encryption you encrypt before you hit transport and decrypt after. e.g. PGP.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_to_Point_Encryption
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption

Wiki makes it sound like point to point is better, this is due to the work that has been put into TLS (Transport Layer Security) so that your https traffic is secure. End to End can be just as effective (e.g. PGP), but you do need to work out how to transport the key for decryption which is a possible weak link.

For the most secure you would use both:

1. Encrypt (using key)
2. Send over Https
3. Receive
4. Decrypt (using key)